# How should we clean up [type-annotation]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[type-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-annotation) has 92 questions and is supposed to be used for [Java's type annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html), based on the tag excerpt and wiki:

> Type-Annotations are released with Java SE 8 release.

However, the [majority](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btype-annotation%5D+and+%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bpython-3.x%5D) of the questions under this tag are actually for [Python's type annotations, or type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5).

My suggestions:

- retag the Python questions to [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting)
- retag the Java questions to something else (possibly [java-type-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-type-annotations)) - AFAIK these annotations are used for additional metadata, not type hints
- possibly synomize [type-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-annotation) to [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting)

There are also [27 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-annotation+-python+-python-3.x+-java) that don't fall under either language, but I'm not a SME for these languages, so I'm not exactly sure what the best course is.

Comment: SME here - TypeScript has type annotations (technical term). I suggest we just update the tag wiki to make the tag generic, the concept is common enough for multiple languages. Although it won't hurt to retag Python's questions to [type-hinting] while we are at it as those ain't, strictly speaking, type annotations. They are close enough, on the other hand, to just consider synonymizing.

Comment: Python type hinting is built on top of its annotations syntax. "type annotations" is an entirely correct term for these annotations. So it's not all that surprising the tag has been co-opted by the Python community.

Comment: I'd say that maybe we should just consider making [type-hinting] a synonym of [type-annotations], @MartijnPieters? Granted, they aren't called the same, but they are similar enough in principle (as we both mentioned), so there doesn't seem to be any harm in synonymizing.

Comment: Are Java's type annotations somehow fundamentally different? Are type annotations not just a form of type hinting? (I can think of two reasons to use a type annotation: because a human will read it, or because a compiler or other tool will parse it; in either case, it seems fair to me to say that a type is being "hinted" to the reader or the parser respectively.) What's wrong with tagging the Java questions about this feature as `[java] [type-hinting]`, and the Python questions as `[python] [type-hinting]`?

Comment: *"AFAIK these annotations are used for additional metadata, not type hints"* - I would agree there. The type hinting is done through generics. Type annotations provide additional meta data about said type. I.E. "cannot be null" or "cannot exceed 100 characters". I kind of find it confusing to call them so specifically type annotations; they're just annotations in the end.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: No, the term is used completely differently in Java. Java has a feature called *Annotations* which allow you to add metadata to methods, interfaces, classes, and enums. Crucially, for a very long time, Java did *not* allow you to annotate types. E.g. you could not write something like `class Option<@NotNull T>`. That is what the *type annotations* feature in Java added: these are *annotations for types*, not *annotating something with a type*.

Comment: There are essentially two problems here: 1) the Java community chose an extremely confusing name for this feature by naming it something that already has a well-defined meaning and 2) this tag makes the same mistake, by using the generic term to apply only to the niche usage.

Comment: How this tag makes more easy to answer these questions in a way that the title/body can't do it?

Comment: Note that [[annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotations)] and [[java-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-annotations)] exist as well.

Answer (score -3):

Collecting the thoughts in the comments, as well as some of my own.

Java seems to have co-opted the term "type annotation" for their own feature, which is a specific use of a Java `@annotation` applied *to* a type. It is not an annotation that indicates a type, it's an annotation that indicates *information about* a type.

For the general-purpose, language-agnostic "ascribing a type to a term", we already have [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting). I don't particularly see a need to have Python-specific version of this. The Java feature, on the other hand, could use a tag, but it's niche enough that it should *not* have the generic name [type-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-annotation).

With that in mind, here's what I'm proposing.

- Rename [type-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-annotation) to something with "Java" in the name, such as [java-type-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-type-annotations) as suggested by OP.
- Retag any Python questions that were incorrectly tagged with [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting). With only 92 questions, this should be doable by-hand.
- Let [type-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-annotation) die a quiet death. If it becomes a problem again, consider blacklisting the name.

Comment: I think "type annotation" is the more general term because "hint" implies that it is not necessary to write it; at least in TypeScript, a type annotation is often mandatory, not merely a "hint", so we use the term "type annotation" and the official docs do, too.

Comment: note that the term *type hinting* means something entirely different in java. Type hints in java refer to explicitly providing the generic types of called methods: `myObj.<SomeType>someMethod(foo, bar);` where `<SomeType>` would be the type hint. Another example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409714/5515060). So I *would **not*** nuke `[type-annotation]` and replace it with `[type-hinting]`

Comment: Just to be sure, aren't those called type *witnesses*? @Lino

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine oh, [you seem to be right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#type-inference-methods). Even though it is the (potentially) official term. Type hint seems also to be used thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @Lino - I am no Java programmer, just wanted to clarift that I understood the spec correctly, and that's how they are officially called. They do seem to function exactly as explicit type annotations / hints in other languages, agreed on that.